# Compressing and decompressing a tar.gz file

Tags: rust, gzip, tar

I'm trying to compress a directory into a `tar.gz` file and decompressing it after using Rust.
I'm using the crates `tar = "0.4.35"` and `flate2 = "1.0.20"`. I'm on Windows.

My code is almost identical to the examples [here](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/rust-cookbook/compression/tar.html#decompress-a-tarball-while-removing-a-prefix-from-the-paths).

```
let tar = File::create("a.tar.gz").unwrap();
let enc = GzEncoder::new(tar, Compression::default());
let mut a = tar::Builder::new(enc);
a.append_dir_all("", "in").unwrap();
```

```
let tar = File::open("a.tar.gz").unwrap();
let dec = GzDecoder::new(tar);
let mut a = Archive::new(dec);
a.unpack("out").unwrap();
```

I'm always getting an error when decompressing:
`thread 'main' panicked at 'called Result::unwrap() on an` Err`value: Custom { kind: InvalidInput, error: TarError { desc: "failed to iterate over archive", io: Custom { kind: InvalidInput, error: "invalid gzip header" } } }', src\main.rs:21:26`

I can open the generated `tar.gz` in 7-Zip without a problem.
What am I doing wrong or is it an issue with the crates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the issue!

Apparently there are reading and writing encoders and decoders in `flate2`. They both have the same name so you can't distinguish them easily when importing. You have to be careful importing the right ones or you'll get strange errors.

In my example I have to import:

```
use flate2::write::{GzEncoder};
use flate2::read::{GzDecoder};
```

Comment: I've been there. What I do is not to `use` those and write the fully qualified `flate2::read::GzDecoder` or `flate2::write::GzDecoder` everywhere to avoid the ambiguity.